# Connection on device is slower than simulator

Tags: ios, network-programming

I'm experiencing longer load times when trying to make requests and download images on my device than I am from my simulator. They are both connected to the same network (my computer and my iPhone/iPad), but the load time is significantly different.

Is this expected? If so, why?

Also, if it makes a difference, I'm using Apple's [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as well as `UIImage`'s `imageWithData:`.

I'm requesting images like this:

`[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImageURLString]]]`

On my simulator, it's downloading an image in 650 miliseconds and on my iPad 4, it's downloading in 1.5 seconds.

Comment: That's not enough detail.  Show the code that performs the connection.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've added one example. If you want other examples, I can provide them.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected.
All components of computer has greater performance, including CPU, memory and network subsystem.

Comment: Sure, but how does that effect a TCP/IP connection?

Comment: WiFi controllers has different performance too, and this difference can be so big. Mobile equipment can be small end low-energy, in computer it's not so important, so performance is bigger.

Comment: "significantly different"?  Nah, it's something else other than the underlying hardware.

Comment: What is model of your Mac?

Comment: Where you run simulator

Comment: Me, or the OP?  You do understand that I'm not the one asking the question, don't you?

Comment: Oh, sorry - my mistake.

Comment: If both are connected the same way (wireless vs. wired) to the same network, I would expect comparable performance.  The main bottleneck in network performance is the physical media.

Answer (score 1):

No, not always - controllers may has different parameters, at least, output power
iPhone4S yas Wi-Fi controller based on same chip, this product: http://www.murata-ws.com/products/spec_sheet.php?type=Type%20SH%202.4GHz%20Wi-Fi%20802.11b/g/n%20Bluetooth%204.0+EDR&record=13

```
WLAN RF Power   +14dBm @n mode / 65Mb/s
```

My Mac mini late 2012 contains this Wi-Fi chip: http://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions/BCM4331

```
The BCM4331 single-chip 802.11n dual-band 3x3 wireless solution enables Wi-Fi products to support 450 Mbps data rates and achieves over 600Mbps (TCP/IP) throughput in simultaneous AP/router configurations.
```

At least 65Mbps in iPhone 4S vs. 450Mbps in Mac mini.

I hope, all's clear now? :)